# How to select items from a list in r based on similar characters in each item?

Tags: r, list, character

I am trying to select some items from the list and group them based on similar characters in each item. For example, I want to group all files with "20130409" and assign them to a directory.
Please, How can I do that?
I tried to used loops but it did not work.

data <- list.files('Output_crop/')

"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130409_20180201_01_T1_B1.tif"  "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130409_20180201_01_T1_B10.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130409_20180201_01_T1_B11.tif" "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130409_20180201_01_T1_B2.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130409_20180201_01_T1_B3.tif"  "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130409_20180201_01_T1_B4.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130409_20180201_01_T1_B5.tif"  "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130409_20180201_01_T1_B6.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130409_20180201_01_T1_B7.tif"  "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130409_20180201_01_T1_B8.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130409_20180201_01_T1_B9.tif"  "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130409_20180201_01_T1_BQA.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130416_20170310_01_T1_B1.tif"  "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130416_20170310_01_T1_B10.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130416_20170310_01_T1_B11.tif" "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130416_20170310_01_T1_B2.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130416_20170310_01_T1_B3.tif"  "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130416_20170310_01_T1_B4.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130416_20170310_01_T1_B5.tif"  "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130416_20170310_01_T1_B6.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130416_20170310_01_T1_B7.tif"  "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130416_20170310_01_T1_B8.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130416_20170310_01_T1_B9.tif"  "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130416_20170310_01_T1_BQA.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130603_20170310_01_T1_B1.tif"  "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130603_20170310_01_T1_B10.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130603_20170310_01_T1_B11.tif" "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130603_20170310_01_T1_B2.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130603_20170310_01_T1_B3.tif"  "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130603_20170310_01_T1_B4.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130603_20170310_01_T1_B5.tif"  "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130603_20170310_01_T1_B6.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130603_20170310_01_T1_B7.tif"  "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130603_20170310_01_T1_B8.tif"
"LC08_L1TP_044033_20130603_20170310_01_T1_B9.tif"  "LC08_L1TP_044033_20130603_20170310_01_T1_BQA.tif"

Comment: `data <- list.files('Output_crop/', pattern = '20130409')`

Comment: use `dir.create` function to create the directory then use `file.copy` + `file.remove` to copy and delete from source

Comment: `data[which(str_detect(data, "20130409"))]`

Comment: Thank for replying. However, what I wanted to do is not using the pattern = "20130409" but used a loop (or a function) to select all the files that have a similar line of character to be group together. It could be "20130409" or "20180609" or else.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a loop by filtering the names by `grepl()`. The function `grepl()` looks for a regex-pattern in a character and returns a boolean value indicating whether it is present or not.

So, if you want to get all elements containing "20130409", you just write:

```
selection = data[grepl("20130409",data)]
```

The vector `selection` then contains only the entries that contained this substring. You can then loop through this vector to move or copy these files.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the unique values (20130409, 20130416, 20130603) with the command:

```
samples <- (unique(substr(data,18,25)))
```

Now you can write a loop that looks for each value among your filenames and group the files together that contain the respective value.
This only works if the value is always in the same position and has the same length.